# Checking if user exists in Oracle Database - java jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

So I have this working code/prepared statement that adds a username and password into a database, however I need to check if the username already exists in the code.

```
public void addUser(Connection conn, PreparedStatement pstmnt, String username, String password) 
    {
        try 
        {
            pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into users values (?,?,?)");
            pstmnt.setInt(1, 0);
            pstmnt.setString(2, username);
            pstmnt.setString(3, password);
            pstmnt.executeUpdate();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) { System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); }

        System.out.println(username + " has been added");
    }
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Using a `unique` constraint in the database does not work?

Comment: What @UwePlonus says -- just enforce the constraint at the database level. This is what a primary key is.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a unique constraint in the DB and handle the exception in addUSer accordingly

Comment: +1, that is the best solution. For example with the statement `ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT users_uq_name UNIQUE (username);`

Answer (score 0):

If there's no many duplicate key risk, you can just try and check the error code if it matches "dup key error" ([Error ORA-00001](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e0.htm#ORA-00001)).

Else you must lock the entire table, check for key existence, update and then commit (which release the lock)